# Bad JSON escape sequence: \U. (check convertible or not)

Tags: json, c#-4.0, json.net

I have the following type of message (JSON) for over 100k records in one of the columns of the excel sheet

```
string message = "{'id': '01','name': 'Rockey','details': 'He is the number one student and a great sports person. ðŸ\u008f´\\U000e0067\\U000e0062\\U000e0073\\U000e0063\\U000e0074\\U000e007f #blackandwhite'}";
```

I am trying to deserialize them but I am getting following error.

> Bad JSON escape sequence: \U

My code is as follows

```
public class Person
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string details { get; set; }
    }
```

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string message = "{'id': '01','name': 'Rockey','details': 'He is the number one student and a great sports person. ðŸ\u008f´\\U000e0067\\U000e0062\\U000e0073\\U000e0063\\U000e0074\\U000e007f #blackandwhite'}";
            message = message.Replace("\\", "\\\\");
            var person=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(message);

        }
```

If I write like above it is working for certain records but fails for other records basically what I observed is the JSON in the excel column is sometimes not in exact valid format and if I did as above some of the other JSON which are not required to replace also replacing and those are failing to Deserialize.
I want to use message.Replace if required only otherwise wanted to Deserialize directly.
How do I know whether or not it is required to replace before converting?
What is the role played by UTF-8 here some developers are saying I need to use UTF-8?

Note:
The Excel sheet is coming from a client we have no authority on that we need to use as it is and they are generating that excel sheet using some tool and column data is JSON only

Comment: Does your raw JSON string really look like `{'id': '01','name': 'Rockey','details': 'He is the number one student and a great sports person. ðŸ´\U000e0067\U000e0062\U000e0073\U000e0063\U000e0074\U000e007f #blackandwhite'}` or did you edit it for the purpose of asking the question?  It is malformed in several ways, including 1) Property names in single quotes not double quotes.  2) Malformed escape sequence `\U000` as per [rfc8259](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259#page-9).

Comment: But perhaps you edited the JSON to turn it into a c# string literal, can you [edit] your question to share the original, raw JSON without any modifications?

Comment: I removed other elements such as city, state, etc but the details elements data are the same.
I know this string can't be convertible to a C# object by deserializing. So If I got the solution to remove such a string from JSON string also be helpful for me.
Or if you provide the details to remove the entire details element from the string also ok for me.